# LINQ query works on LINQPAD throws Error on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
var data = (from prod in db.ref_ProductAvail
            group prod by new { prod.storeOfAccount, prod.serviceName } into g
            orderby g.Key.storeOfAccount
            join branch in db.ref_Branch 
            on g.Key.storeOfAccount equals branch.code
            select new
            {
                branchCode = g.Key.storeOfAccount,
                branchName = branch.description,
                serviceName = g.Key.serviceName,
                svcCount = g.Key.serviceName.Count()
            }).ToList();
```

My Query works on LINQPAD but throws this error on C# > 
DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.Parameter name: input,

as I've searched for a solution I failed to found the exact solution to my problem, also removing `ToList` or using `IEnumerable` does work but I cannot use `foreach`.

Comment: removing `ToList` "solves" your issue, because query is not executed until you make it `ToList` or iterate it with foreach

Comment: LINQPAD lets you do LINQ manipulations & filtering on IEnumerable generic collections, linq-to-sql is a wrapper that uses LINQ  as syntactic sugar to query the database, so not everything that works with LINQ on collections, works in linq-to-sql. They're totally two different things.

Comment: do you guys have any idea what i could try next for a solution? thanks

Comment: found that the .count on my query is causing the error
svcCount = g.Key.serviceName.Count()

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you got it right. the error should be in `g.Key.serviceName.Count()` because this expression is trying to count number of characters in `serviceName` string. which is not convertible to sql. If you want to achieve the same thing, you can try something like

```
var data = (from prod in db.ref_ProductAvail
            group prod by new { prod.storeOfAccount, prod.serviceName } into grouping
            orderby grouping.Key.storeOfAccount
            from g in grouping
            join branch in db.ref_Branch 
            on g.Key.storeOfAccount equals branch.code
            select new
            {
                branchCode = g.Key.storeOfAccount,
                branchName = branch.description,
                serviceName = g.Key.serviceName,
                svcCount =  grouping.Select(x=>x.Key.serviceName).Distinct().Count()
            }).ToList();
```

Haven't tested it though

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply it does get rid of the error however it also caused my data to duplicate. might try to change some things, atleast i know now where to look thanks